# My PMTA server was not successfully installed

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, centos, linux-mint

My PMTA fail to install successfully the error code was  job for PMTA. service failed because the control process exited with error code. see system status pmta. service and journal-ke[image]

Answer (score 0):

The image is *very* hard to read, but it looks like the command failed because PolicyKit failed to check if you have permission to stop or restart the `pmta` service, and the error has nothing to do with the actual `pmta` service.

The "core" error message seems to be:

```
org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: Cannot determine user of subject (polkit-error-quark, 0)
```

Is your session started up in some unusual way? Or is something limiting your session's access to the `/proc` filesystem?

See:
https://mellowhost.com/blog/unable-to-register-authentication-agent-gdbus-errororg-freedesktop-policykit1-error-failed-cannot-determine-user-of-subject-cyberpanel-centos-7.html

If your `/proc` filesystem is hidden from your shell session, e.g. by mounting `/proc` with a `hidepid=2` mount option, then the `polkitd` user needs to be allowed to see `/proc`. The procedure recommended in the link is:

```
groupadd nohideproc                    # add a group that will be exempt from /proc hiding 
usermod -a -G nohideproc polkitd       # add user polkitd to that group
mount -o remount,rw,hidepid=2,gid=nohideproc /proc   # remount /proc with the "gid=nohideproc" mount option added
systemctl restart polkit
systemctl restart polkit    # (do this twice)
```

Once this is done, you should also add the `gid=nohideproc` mount option for the `/proc` filesystem in `/etc/fstab`, to make the change completely persistent.